# C# string replace for website names

Tags: c#

I am trying to do a string replace for website names. Here is the code:

```
 string output = input.Replace("C:\Design\Website\", "Someting");
 TextBox.Text = osc.output;
```

The code is incorrect as there is an issue `\` with these marks. How can I fix my code?

Answer (score 1):

You need to escape the `\`:

Either:

```
"C:\\Design\\Website\\"
```

Or:

```
@"C:\Design\Website\"
```